# JavaScript: Cross-browser "browser plugin" detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a script that will allow me to detect if a user has Windows Media Player installed, or Quicktime, or Flash, or Silverlight...

Ideally, this would be jQuery plugin, but any script will do.

Do you know of one you can recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PluginDetect](http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/) seems to work pretty good. You can generate a minified version of the script and only select the plugins you want to detect and functions you need.

Comment: +100K if I could.  I searched forever before finding this.  It works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jqPlugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqplugin).

Comment: I tried that one first, but it detected WindowsMediaPlayer support on my Mac, so I don't think it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple has written a script to do this.](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/detectplugins.html)
With it you can run functions like:

- `detectQuickTime()`
- `detectFlash()`
- `detectDirector()`
- `detectWindowsMedia()`
- `detectReal()`